# Variable inside request

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, request

I want to parse body outside of request. But i can not figure out a way to get it outside of the request function. Can you please show me how? Or at least give me an example. I do not understand it.

```
"use strict"
var robotsParser = require('robots-parser');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs')
let url = 'http://google.de/robots.txt'

request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    //console.log(body)        
    robots = robotsParser(url, body)
    var reserveisDisallowed = robots.isDisallowed('http://google.de/maps/reserve/api/', '*')
    console.log(reserveisDisallowed)
})
```

Comment: Please explain more, where you want to execute this code. What is body, Why U not using response?

Comment: I just need the body
the body is returned correctly. I just want to get the content of body outside of requests scope.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery deferred, if you want to execute this instruction after success callback as:

```
var $deferred = $.Deferred(),
    robots,
    globalBody;

$deferred.done(function(body){
    robots = robotsParser(url, body);
    globalBody = body; //After here globalBody object has body available. Do whatever you want to do now.    
    var reserveisDisallowed = robots.isDisallowed('http://google.de/maps/reserve/api/', '*')
    console.log(reserveisDisallowed)
});

request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    //console.log(body)        
  $deferred.resolve(body);
})
```

or **if U just want body available outside, simply use 'globalBody' variable in your code**

As:

```
request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    //console.log(body)        
    robots = robotsParser(url, body);
    globalBody = body;
    var reserveisDisallowed = robots.isDisallowed('http://google.de/maps/reserve/api/', '*')
    console.log(reserveisDisallowed)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, i am using Node and would like to not use jquery and then have to mock the window just for this. What do i need to look into or understand in order to keep this vanilla?